# Suppose that $f_n$ are increasing function defined on $[0, 1]$ and converges to $f$ in measure.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose that $f_n$ are increasing function defined on $[0, 1]$ and converges to $f$ in measure. Prove that if $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=x_0$, then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n(x_0)=f(x_0)$

Can anyone help me how to prove above statement? I don't know how to use the fact that $(f_n)$ is increasing.

Comment: The claim is false. Let $f_n(x)=x^n$, $f(x)=0$ and $x_0=1$

Comment: Does "converge in measure" mean that $\int_0^1(f(x)-f_n(x))dx\to 0$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Does $f_n(x)=x^{n}$ increases on [0, 1] as $n$ increases?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I edited the post.

Comment: @Arthur Thanks for your comment. However can you elaborate little bit more how can I use it when proving the statement?

Comment: Hints: $f_n$ is increasing and  has a subsequence that converges ae.

Comment: @Matematleta Since there exists a subsequence $\{f_n_k\}$ that converges to $f$ almost everywhere, $f(x)=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}f_n_k(x)$ holds at $\mu$-almost every point. Since $f_n$ is increasing, $f(x)=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}f_n_k(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow}f_n(x)$ for point $x$, $\mu$-almost every point. Is it right? But how do we know if above equation holds for $x=x_0$? Thanks for your help.

Comment: More hints: since $f_n$ is increasing, it either converges or diverges to infinity.  But if $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ then....?